# How to get the list of items of a particular class using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a MVC application.

I want to display the list of Items of a perticuler object in View.

In below class List of InventoryItem is the part of the Product which can have n number of items.

I have following classes in model.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<InventoryItem> Inventory { get; set; }
}


public class InventoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Now I have created the one product with four Inventory Items...

```
 public List<Product> GetAllProductList()
        {

            Product oProduct = new Product();

            oProduct = oProdRepo.GetProductById(1);

            oProduct.Inventory = new List<InventoryItem>
            {
                new InventoryItem { Location = oLocationRepo.GetLocationById(1),Quantity = 234,Product = oProduct},
                new InventoryItem { Location = oLocationRepo.GetLocationById(2),Quantity = 123,Product = oProduct},
                new InventoryItem { Location = oLocationRepo.GetLocationById(3),Quantity = 642,Product = oProduct},
                new InventoryItem { Location = oLocationRepo.GetLocationById(4),Quantity = 534,Product = oProduct}

            };

            InventoryProductList.Add(oProduct);

        return InventoryProductList;

    }
```

Above method creates the Product with 4 Inventory Items. Its working perfectly.

Now I wan to display the above Inventory Items i.e 4 in the grid columns .

I am stuck on how to show the Grid columns for these InventoryItems  ?

I have this view code....

```
@model IEnumerable<StockWatchServices.DomainClass.Product>
     @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns => 
                        {
                            columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Product Name").SetWidth(175).Sortable(true).Filterable(true);                      
                       1->       columns.Add(c => c.Inventory.Where(r=>r.Location.Nam ????? ) What to write here ? 
                        2 Column->  ? 
                        3 Column->  ? 
                        4 Column->  ?  

                        }).WithPaging(5)
```

[image]

Comment: Are `Location` static or they can change? Does all `Product` have always same 4 inventory items?

Comment: they might change , but right now I want to create it with 4 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, it seems, `Grid` does not allow adding same property name more the once you can create `table` manually:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @{
                var locationNames = Model.SelectMany(n => n.Inventory).Select(n => n.Location.Name).Distinct().ToArray();
                foreach (var locationName in locationNames)
                {
                    <td>@locationName</td>
                }
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach(var product in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach(var columnName in locationNames)
                {
                    <td>@product.Inventory.Single(i => i.Location.Name == columnName).Quantity</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and apply some CSS to that

Comment: This works... Thanks A Lot for your efforts... But I am still wondering about last code of grid, why dont they allow to show columns twice in grid... I have added the MVC.Grid from NuGate package its from CodePlex.

Comment: I've changed and undeleted my other answer. It seems I found a solution for duplicate columns

Comment: You have solution for duplicate columns ?

Answer (score 0):

I would first get all possible location names and then create a column for each one of them:

```
var locationNames = Model.SelectMany(n => n.Inventory).Select(n => n.Location.Name).Distinct().ToArray();
foreach(var locationName in locationNames)
{
    var columnName = locationName;
    columns.Add(m => m.Inventory.Single(n => n.Location.Name == columnName).Quantity, columnName).Titled(columnName);
}
```

**EDIT**
I've downloaded same [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/) NuGet package and you need to use overload of `Columns.Add` that accepts `columnName` parameter otherwise it will complain about column duplicates

**Caveat** is that this will work assuming that all `Product` will have same list of `Location` names otherwise it will throw exception

Comment: `var locationNames = Model.SelectMany(n => n.Inventory).Select(n => n.Location.Name).Distinct().ToArray();
                            foreach(var locationName in locationNames)
                            {
                                columns.Add(c => c.Inventory.Single(r => r.Location.Name == locationName).Quantity).SetWidth(12);
                            }` I have added this code but its says Column 'Quantity' already exist in the grid.... I am I missing some syntax ? It executes first loop properly...

Comment: If you add `Titled(locationName)` does it help? I don't know how it determines duplicate columns

Comment: I cant use the Titled property, Its show error when I used 'Titled' keyword... GridView.MVC.IColumn.Titled can not be used as a method...

Comment: `columns.Add(c => c.Inventory.Single(r => r.Location.Name == locationName).Quantity).Title(locationName).SetWidth(12);`

Comment: So how does it work above `columns.Add(c => c.Name).Titled("Product Name").SetWidth(175)`? Do the same here `Add(c => ...).Titled(columnName).SetWidth(12)`. Maybe check brackets. Check my updated answer. You'll need to store `loactionName` in a loca variabe in the loop

Comment: I got the problem, It dont allow to add the same property twice... If I again try to add the Name property , with different column name, still its throws the error... what If I wan to use simple Table , not the grid , How can I add <td> in loop ?